# Difference between transformation and projection

Tags: linear-transformations, transformation, projective-geometry, projection

We know that world coordinates $(x_w, y_w)$ transform to viewport coordinates $(x_v, y_v)$ which are the physical device coordinates. And during projection, any point $(x, y, z)$ projects to $(x, y)$ onto the projection plane. My question is: Are projection and transformation both the same?
Please explain it with a small example. I want to understand intuition rather than details proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projections are the subset of transformations which reduce the size of a space.
That is, all projections are transformations, but not all transformations are projections.

Projections often come up in linear algebra and functions between real numbers, in which a projection means that the *dimensionality* of the space is reduced.
As that seems to be the case here, let's say that $x_w, y_w, x_v, y_v \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then $(x_w, y_w) \rightarrow (x_v, y_v)$ is a transformation, while $(x_w, y_w) \rightarrow x_v$ would be both a transformation and a projection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How do I improve this? I have answered his original question and then provided an example. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Comment: @fibo give two example where transformation is holding but projection not. And projection is holding but transformation not.

Comment: @fibo one example all transformation isn't projection... Please

Comment: @Niyon all projections are transformations. I can't give you an example of when an operation is a projection but not a transformation because that doesn't exist. Even the identity transformation (x, y) --> (x, y) is still a transformation, meaning that the most basic of projections (x, y) --> x is still a transformation as well.

Comment: @fibo projections (x, y) --> x give one example?

Comment: @fibo please explain " (x, y) --> x"-what it means??